# Display Decimal number asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

how can i display Decimal number 50.00 to be like 50 in Update view.
my view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.num, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "N" ,type = "number", min = "0",max="100"})
```

viewModel:

```
public string num { get; set; }
```

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.num, "{0:0}",  new { @class ...})`

Comment: i tried this way but it's Not working

Comment: Then you did not try it correctly because it **does** work

Comment: here is how my code after updating it, but unfortunately didn't work:@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.num,"{0:0}",new {...}

Comment: OMG, Just noticed you question is how to format a decimal, and then you model is a string!

Comment: yes maybe that's why is not working:(, yes it's string and it's to late to change it, it's long story,thank you for your help